# Same variable name used twice but program doesn't throw error?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

In the code below for linked list

Why doesn't Link `newLink = new Link()` give an error the second time `thelist.insertfirst()` is called as the `newlink` is already defined?

MY UNDERSTANDING - Scope of the variable `newlink` is the method `insertfirst()`.

`Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);`

When a link `newlink` is created the variable `newlink` holds the memory address of the link object created.

`newLink.next = first;`

`first` is a link variable which contains the memory address of a link object.

Then, the `newlink.next()` is pointed towards the `object contained at the memory address of the variable first`.

`first = newLink;`

Then, the variable `first` is pointed towards the `newlink`. This means that first now contains the memory address of the object `newlink` (newlink itself contains the address to actual object).

When the method is finished, The variable 'newlink' is lost but we don't care as we have already `copied` the memory address (in the `next` field) of the link objects.

Is this analogy correct?

```
class Link
   {
   public int iData;              // data item
   public double dData;           // data item
   public Link next;              // next link in list

   public Link(int id, double dd) // constructor
     {
      iData = id;                 // initialize data
      dData = dd;                 // ('next' is automatically
     }                           //  set to null)
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class LinkList
   {
   private Link first;            // ref to first link on list



   public LinkList()              // constructor
      {
      first = null;               // no links on list yet
      }

                              // insert at start of list
   public void insertFirst(int id, double dd)
      {                           // make new link
      Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);//######################################## DOESN'T THROW ERROR 
      newLink.next = first;       // newLink --> old first
      first = newLink;            // first --> newLink
      }

   }  // end class LinkList
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class LinkListApp
   {
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      LinkList theList = new LinkList();  // make new list

      theList.insertFirst(22, 2.99);      // insert four items
      theList.insertFirst(44, 4.99);
      theList.insertFirst(66, 6.99);
      theList.insertFirst(88, 8.99);

      }  // end main()
   }  // end class LinkListApp
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: why ```Link newLink``` not throwing error? it's because its defined locally. if you do: ```this.first``` then you will use the class one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there is no error here. It’s very, very common to have a local variable in a method and then call that method several times. And yes, you may say that it is not the same variable the second time you call the method since the variable is created every time the method is executed.

The reason why you cannot declare two variables with the same name in the same scope is that then you wouldn’t know which is which. This problem is not in your code. Each time your method is called, a variable named `newLink` is created and assigned a value. So when in the following two lines you use the name of this variable, it is of course the newly created one. It’s not the one that was created the last time the method was called, nor the time before the last time. No confusion is possible. This is the reason for allowing it.

Scope is about where in the program, the text if you will, you can use a certain name. In this case between its declaration and the nearest enclosing right curly brace three lines further down. Scope is *not* about how many times you are allowed to invoke that piece of code and create a new variable with the same name each time. In other words, within one scope you may only **type** the declaration of a variable with a certain name once when you write the program, but you may **use** that declaration for actually creating variables as many times as you like when the program is running.

And yes, your description, your analogy is correct.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you.